# How to set up nested subfolder to subdomain Nginx 301 redirects

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to set up Nginx redirects that will rewrite any URL from several older forum setups to a new forum. The older forums ran from subfolders, while the current forum is running from a subdomain of the same site.

So, for example, I want **ANY** request to site.com/ask to be redirected to the front page of forum.site.com. Since I'm dealing with 3 old forums, I tried to set up a nested redirect like this:

```
location ~ ^/\~([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
  location ~ ^/\~ask/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://forum.site.com$1 permanent;     
  }

  location ~ ^/\~forum/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://forum.site.com$1 permanent;     
  }

  location ~ ^/\~qa/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://forum.site.com$1 permanent;     
  }
}
```

With the above rules, only the first one works and partially. For example, a request to site.com/ask gets redirected to forum.site.com, which is fine, but any request to, say, site.com/ask/what-is-this goes to forum.site.com/404.

Request to site.com/forum and site.com/qa do not work at all.

I'm sure there's a simpler way of doing this, but I don't want to spend several days trying to figure it out.

Your input is welcome and appreciated.

Edit:

Not getting anywhere with the above code, I reduced it to this:

```
location ~ ^/\~([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
            location ~ ^/\~(qa|forum|ask)/(.*)$ {
                  rewrite ^/~(qa|forum|ask)/(.*)$ http://forum.site.com$1 permanent;
            }
    }
```

But the result is still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: In your comment you mention `site.com/ask`, but your code is for `site.com/~ask/`. Which is right?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. It's site.com/ask, site.com/forum, and site.com/qa. Is there are better and more concise way of doing this?

Comment: Added a modification of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you want to redirect user to the main page of your forum regardless of what page he came to. Try this.

```
location /qa/ {
    return 301 http://forum.site.com;
}

location /ask/ {
    return 301 http://forum.site.com;
}

location /forum/ {
    return 301 http://forum.site.com;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. a step closer, but still needs tweaking. With this, requests to site.com/forum, for example, go to forum.site.com, which is good. But a request to site.com/forum/how-to-do-this goes to forum.site.com/404. How can I tweak it so that all requests go to forum.site.com?

Comment: This code redirects `site.com/forum/how-to` to `forum.site.com/forum/how-to`. If you want redirect to `forum.site.com` remove `$request_uri` part from code above.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks. You may remove the same from your code to show the correct answer.